# How to view Haskell's documentation using Haddock?

Tags: haskell, haddock

For example, how would I view the docs for Data.List.group as I could on [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html)?

If I try to use Haddock as:

```
$ haddock Data.List                                   
<no location info>: error: module ‘Data.List’ is a package module
$ haddock Data.List.group                            
target ‘Data.List.group’ is not a module name or a source file
```

On the other hand, I know that these html docs exist in my computer under the `/usr/local/share/doc` directory.

Or am I mistaken and this is not what Haddock does?

Comment: I believe `haddock` is for generating (not looking up) documentation.

Comment: @Alec err, then how I access Haskell's documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `haddock` command generates documentation in HTML. To view it you use any web browser by pointing it at the generated file. There should be an `index.html` file, so you can view it with:

```
firefox index.html
```

**Update:** If you are using [Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) then `stack haddock` will generate the documentation for your project, and also for all the dependencies.

Comment: So Haskell doesn't have any system/tool for viewing documentation in itself?

Comment: @Rishav: no. Just use your favorite web browser.